# Jmeter : Running on remote machine fails Error: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, remote-server

I want to test basic functionality of running a Jmeter test on Remote System
I have done the following :

1. Same version of java on both machines
2. Same subnetwork for both machines
3. Set up Test of Host Jmeter
4. create RMI keystore at host system and also add same file to client system
5. add client IP address to remote_host variable in the jmeter properties file
6. start jmeter server at client end
7. Run the test in both GUI and Non GUI mode alternatively still same error is persistent

[image: The below is error when running on non - GUI mode]

Please suggest me what else shall be done, and if I have done something wrong let me know

Answer (score 0):

JMeter master communicates with slave(s) via [RMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)

It meant that:

- Master needs to be able to reach the slave to send the [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
- Slave needs to be able to connect to the master to send back [results and metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

The [RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) which are used for the bi-directional communication need to be opened in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)). By default slave listens for the incoming connections on port `1099` so start with checking whether it's open and reachable from the master. The error you're getting means that the master cannot establish RMI connection to the slave using the default port.

For receiving the metrics from the slave JMeter uses random ports. If you cannot open all ports you can specify the desired ones using `client.rmi.localport` property, JMeter will open up to 3 ports starting with the port you provide via the property.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please help me understand how can I check if master is able to access the default port 1099?